# Google Maps for Mobile - Blue Circle of Uncertainty

Tags: google-maps, location, google-maps-mobile, uncertainty

When GPS positioning is unavailable (or even when it is available sometimes), Google Maps for mobile shows a blue circle of uncertainty around the blue self-localization dot.  What exactly (statistically) does this blue circle represent?

Is it the 95% confidence interval?  Since it does change in size, I am assuming it is some representation of accuracy.  Is it just a rough guideline or are there are some actual numbers going in to an accuracy calculation which is then represented visually?

Answer (score 0):

[We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) You may get your current location via [`getLastLocation` position](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29).